# AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, insert, dml-operations

I want to update a record that has recently been created.

Trigger:

```
trigger TTCaseTrigger on Custom_Case__c (after insert) {
        
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.new[0].TT_Case_Source__c != 'Email') {
            TT_CaseEmailService.createCaseManually(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
public static void createCaseManually(List<Custom_Case__c > ttManualCase) {

    for(Custom_Case__c tt : ttManualCase){
        tt.TT_Case_Source__c = 'Other';
        tt.Opened__c = Datetime.now();
    }
    update ttManualCase;
}
```

When I try to save the record, I get the following error.

> AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Answer (score 2):

That's because records contained in trigger context variables are read-only in `after` triggers (and you're passing trigger.new, a trigger context variable, into `createCaseManually()`).

In this case, since you're operating on the records going through the trigger (and not other, related records), this should be a `before` trigger. "Before" triggers allow you to make changes to the record before they get saved to the underlying database, so you'll also be able to get rid of the `update ttManualCase;`

The `if(Trigger.new[0].TT_Case_Source__c != 'Email') {` bit should be moved from your trigger into `createCaseManually()` (and you should almost certainly be performing the `TT_Case_Source__c` check for every record, not just the first).

That said, this trigger is simple enough that I would consider doing this as a record-triggered flow instead (selecting the "optimize for fast field updates" makes it act similarly to a "before" trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Since data is not yet committed to database and record is still in read-only mode to perform further updates on the same record. You can check order of execution here - [Salesforce Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

As suggested by Derek, you should either covert the trigger to `before trigger` or also you can use flow with fast field updates which also acts in before context.